# DOMParser Typescript- Parsing HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, domparser

I'm running into some trouble with the DOMParser. I'm  using intelliJ IDE and writing in Typescript.

Here is my code:

```
  public domparser = new DOMParser();
  this.domdoc = this.domparser.parseFromString(this.xmlDoc, 'text/xml');
  console.log("domdoc: " + this.domdoc);
```

I'm seeing 
`domdoc: [object XMLDocument]` in my console.

Any suggestions on how to print the XML document, rather than just '[object XMLDocument]'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and the wildcard  `*` to select all the xml element.

```
 public domparser = new DOMParser();
 this.domdoc = this.domparser.parseFromString(this.xmlDoc, 'text/xml');
 let elements = this.domdoc.querySelectorAll("*");
 for (element of elements){
   console.log(element.innerHTML);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm getting 'domdoc: {"location":null}...that's not quite what I wanted...

Comment: @MeenaMana, do you want to get the exact text message of you xml file?

Comment: Yes. @edkeveked

Comment: @MeenaMana, could you please put in your question your XML content? it will be easier to query it

Comment: It's copyright-protected so I couldn't do that...basically it's a list of names of programs.

Comment: I think your solution works but there's something wrong with the XML Document, it's not getting the entire document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161145/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-meena-mana).

Comment: @MeenaMana, Could you please tell me more what part of the xml document is not included?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

`console.log("domdoc: " + this.domdoc);` this line need some changes. Please remove the string "domdoc:" appended with the object.

Final code looks like:

```
  public domparser = new DOMParser();  
  this.domdoc = this.domparser.parseFromString(this.xmlDoc, 'text/xml');
  console.log(this.domdoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop like the first answer cannot be used in Angular 11.

### This can't be used

```
for (element of elements){
}
```

### This can be used

```
let parsedXMLResponse = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString("some string value", "text/xml");
let result = parsedXMLResponse.getElementsByTagName("<name of tag>");
```